# Black header react native when upgrading from 0.52 to 0.59

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting an weird error in android after upgrading from react native 0.52 to 0.59. There is a black header which I can't inspect also. The component seems to similar to status bar. I haven't written any code for this but still getting this. Following is my code.

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import Setup from "./src/boot/setup";
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
import './ReactotronConfig';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <Setup />;
  }
}
```

setup.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { StyleProvider } from "native-base";

import App from "../App";
import getTheme from "../theme/components";
import variables from "../theme/variables/commonColor";

export default class Setup extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <StyleProvider style={getTheme(variables)}>
            <View />
          </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

refer following image for error - [image]

Comment: Could you try `paddingTop: 24` ?

Comment: @hongdevelop on what? <View>?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @hongdevelop - didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading I guess actionbar code was generated in styles.xml. Replaced DarkActionBar to NoActionBar in styles.xml. Modified my styles.xml from

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>    
</style>

<style name="Dialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
     <item name="colorPrimary">#00EEDD</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00EEDD</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">#00EEDD</item>
 </style>
```

to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>    
</style>

<style name="Dialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
     <item name="colorPrimary">#00EEDD</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00EEDD</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">#00EEDD</item>
 </style>
```

I inspected my apk via layout inspector in android studio and found that the element was actionbar. So searched for the solution and found this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9rcKZUm0zM